# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load jni-input: findLibrary returned null

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

First,I use NDK in the MainActivity,it works fine.:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView textView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    EventInput eventInput=new EventInput();
    textView.setText(eventInput.eventInject());// NDK
}
}
```

EventInput.java like this:

```
public class EventInput {
static {
    System.loadLibrary("jni-input");
}
public native String eventInject();
}
```

Then,I remove the MainActivity and in the ***boot*** broadcast receiver I start a service ,and used ndk in service`s ***onCreate method***,like this:

```
  @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    try {
        EventInput mockEvent=new EventInput();
        Log.d("jni",mockEvent.eventInject());
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And I push it to /system/app to make it be a system app which will listen the ***boot broadcast*** and start the service.But it runs with:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load jni-input: findLibrary returned null
```

Comment: Check your lib name if it is libjni-input.X or not and stored under project's lib folder.

Comment: I have checked it .It confused me very much.If I started the service in an Activity,ndk can be used in service.But when I remove the Activity, the ndk reports error if it were used in service

Comment: I wonder apk in /system/app  how to deal with .so files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it myself. In compared with regular app,the nativelibrarydirectories of apk in /system/app are `/vender/lib` and `/ system/lib` by default which are the search-path for loading `.so` file.So, It works well when I push my `.so file` in /system/lib.

Comment: That won't work in a shipping app, so that probably isn't a real "solution" for you.

Comment: I am confused about it.

Comment: The Play Store will not install your libraries to `/system/lib`.